# Pagination AJAX Jquery Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, laravel

I´m working on a project wehere i load different workout videos from the Database according to the user level.

(Sorry if my code is not "clean" i´m still learning )

```
//First Exercises from DB
    $uebungen = true;
    $uebungAnzahl = 0;
    $uebungPages = 0;

    //LevelId from loged in User

    $levelId = auth()->user()->level->id;
    //Number from all Exercises <= LevelId
    $uebungTotal =  Uebung::where('level_id', '<=', $levelId)->count();

    if ($uebungTotal) {

        //Number of possible Ajax Calls

        $uebungPages =  ceil($uebungTotal / $this->uebungPerPage);
        //Übungen <= LevelId
        $uebungen = Uebung::select('id', 'url', 'beschreibung', 'level_id', 'kategorie_id')->with('levels', 'kategories')->where('level_id', '<=', $levelId)->orderBy('level_id')->take($this->uebungPerPage)->get();
        //Number of exercises from DB
        $uebungAnzahl = $uebungen->count();
    }

    return view('training.index', compact('uebungen', 'uebungPages', 'uebungAnzahl'));
}

/**
 * Load Data from the Database
 */

public function loadData($request)
{
    //Page handeld to AJAX
    $page = $request;
    //From which record from DB
    $skip = $page * $this->uebungPerPage;

    $levelId = auth()->user()->level->id;

    //Eloquent with skip($skip)
    $uebungen = Uebung::select('id', 'url', 'beschreibung', 'level_id', 'kategorie_id')->with('levels', 'kategories')->where('level_id', '<=', $levelId)->orderBy('level_id')->skip($skip)->take($this->uebungPerPage)->get();

    return response($uebungen);
}
```

Below here is the code where i load  the URL from the DB an put them into an iframe.

```
<script>
     "use strict";

    $('#load-data').on('click',function(){
        //Load page from Button
        let page = $(this).attr('data-page');
        
        let nextPage = parseInt(page)+1;
        
        if( nextPage < $(this).attr('data-totalpages') ){
          
          $(this).attr('data-page',parseInt(page)+1);  
        }
        else{
            //Button wil not display
            $(this).hide();
        }
          //Load Video
    $.get("{{ URL::to('/uebung/load-data') }}/"+page,function(data){

          $.each(data,function(i,value){
            
              // deklaration  t as div
                var t = $("<div class='bild'></div>");               
                  
                t.append($ ("<p>",{
                    html : '<iframe width="516" height="315" type="text/html"src="'+value.url+'""allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
                    }))                                                 
           
                t.append($("<p>",{
            html: 'Übung: '+value.beschreibung}))
            
            .append($("<p>",{
                html: 'Level: '+value.levels.levelbeschreibung}))
                .append($("<p>",{
                    html: 'Kategorie: '+value.kategories.kategorie }))
 
            $('.video').append(t);
              
          });
          
        } );              
    })
   </script>
```

I want to includ that after 2 Exercises the Load Video button should disappear and you have to click on next page where you have to load the next videos.